# Finding google sheets owner name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any option to print the user name that the google sheet file belongs to him? The one that resolved the comments the author gave him?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Select **File**
2. Select **Details**

[image: Details in file menu]

3. The **owner** is displayed

[image: Document details]

Answer (score 0):

The GetOwner() function returns the Owner User of the Spreadhseet.

```
function getUserName()
{
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  thisOwner = ss.getOwner();
  Logger.log(thisOwner);
}
```

Reference:
[Spreadsheet.getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getowner)